# SQL Server 2008 Error when restoring DB backup: "specified cast is not available"

Tags: sql-server-2008, database, sql, restore

I was using SSMS to restore a database backup onto another database in a SQL Server 2008 instance, when I received the error message: "specified cast is not available".

The backup was made on a SQL Server 2005 instance.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I can't recall/find what causes it</strike>

[Your backup is most likely password protected](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/11/02/restore-database-fails-while-trying-to-restore-password-protected-backup-set-from-ssms.aspx)

You can do a manual [RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) without using the GUI